# Logical_And in 2d Image Array using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, pixel, logical-operators

I have 2 image arrays that I am trying to perform a 'Logical And', However the logical_and operator in Numpy is not yielding me the right image. it just gives me a black image.

Here are pieces of code

```
    # iterating  an array the BIG O will be O(n^2)
    for x in range(0, height1-1):
        for y in range(0, width1-1):
            image1X = image1.getpixel((x, y))
            image2X = image2.getpixel((x, y))
            imageArrayTemp[y][x] = image1X and image2X
```

This works perfectly however when i try this

```
     intesect_array = np.logical_and(imageArray1,imageArray2)
```

and convert back to image it is not yielding me the above result. Aren't these 2 suppose to do the same thing?.

Can you please guide on the same?.

Comment: Probably going to depend on how you're doing `imageArray` and `getpixel`.  Does your loopy code work with `imageArray1[x, y]` etc?  In general the two methods should be interchangable.

Comment: yes it works fine with the images, it should be interchangeable however numpy logical_and is not working.

Comment: That's not what I asked.